# Is it appropriate to contact the SO team on Fanatic badge progress?

Tags: support, activity-badges

Would it be appropriate to email the Stack Overflow team to check how far along I am on the Fanatic badge?

Comment: Now that you can check your own progress by using the calendar in your profile, this is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this once upon a blue moon. Based on the response I got, it seemed like they were discouraging it.

1. I suspect team@stackoverflow.com gets way too many e-mails to handle as it is.
2. The system works, but has (according to what I was told) some undocumented behaviors to ensure that you have really "visited."
3. Again, from what I was told, it didn't sound like checking a user's progress on those badges was trivial.

Just keep visiting. That's the behavior they're trying to encourage anyway. :) They don't want you to *stop* visiting every day just because you got a badge. :)

Comment: They wouldn't want users to visit 'blindly' for the badge too, I guess

Answer (score 2):

I too contacted them - to find out whether I'd miscounted.  They sent me a record of when I'd been seen. It turned out there was an extra day's break in my record which I'd not accounted for - so instead of being day 102 it was about day 97.  My fanatic badge arrived on the correct schedule.

I'd suggest not contacting them unless you're pretty sure that the badge is overdue.